# Retrofit Dynamic ResponseBody

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

I am planning to make one common service class with the use of Retrofit,

```
@GET
Call<ResponseBody> makeGetRequest(@Url String url);

@POST
Call<ResponseBody> makePostRequest(@Url String url, @Body RequestBody parameters);
```

In this code i need to pass (ResponseBody) as a dynamic JSON POJO class name , Like LoginRes

Say for Example ,

```
Call<LoginRes> // But this class will be dynamic
```

I will pass ResponseBody but that ResponseBody does not know which class i wanted to prefer.

why i want this because , after result

```
gson.fromJson(response, LoginRes.class);
```

so, after getting result from Retrofit we again need to convert to gson.fromJson.

so i wanted to pass dynamic Response as Retrofit so that it will response according to my pojo class,

I know this is working fine when i pass LoginRes instead of ResponseBody because as i already told to Response that we need that response in LoginRes.

So if i pass

```
Call<LoginRes> // if i pass this way its working fine no need to convert my response i can access my all properties from that LoginRes class directly.
```

This is my example to call a Web service.

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.makePostRequest("/Buyer/LoginApp", requestBody);
```

This is how i call the Service.

Let me know if i am unclear with explanation of my problem.

waiting for some good response and suggestions on this.

Thanks 
Madhav

Comment: So you want to have the same function that can convert the JSON response to various, possibly completely unrelated, classes?

Comment: actually , if i can pass with ResponseBody<LoginRes> dynamically or a different way .. i need suggestions on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Handle GET,POST or OTHER method Like this,**

```
if (methodType.equalsIgnoreCase(CommonConfig.WsMethodType.GET)) {
                apicall = getClient(CommonConfig.WsPrefix).create(ApiInterface.class).makeGetRequest(url + CommonConfig.getQueryString(new Gson().toJson(requestBody)), getAllHeader);
 } else if (methodType.equalsIgnoreCase(CommonConfig.WsMethodType.POST)) {
                apicall = getClient(CommonConfig.WsPrefix).create(ApiInterface.class).makePostRequest(url, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), new Gson().toJson(requestBody)), getAllHeader);
 }
```

**Handle Response Like this.**

```
apicall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                                @Override
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
}

 @Override
 public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

}
}
```

**Retrofit Code**

```
private Retrofit getClient(String WsPrefix) {
        //TODO 60 to 30 second at everywhere
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(WsPrefix)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }
```

**Common Interface**

```
interface ApiInterface {

        @GET
        Call<ResponseBody> makeGetRequest(@Url String url, @HeaderMap() Map<String, String> header);

        @POST
        Call<ResponseBody> makePostRequest(@Url String url, @Body RequestBody requestBody, @HeaderMap() Map<String, String> header);
}
```

**ApiCallback**

```
public interface ApiCallback {
      void success(String responseData);
      void failure(String responseData);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky but you'll need to use a custom Retrofit Converter Factory with a custom GsonBuilder which uses a custom JsonDeserializer.

Furthermore you should define an interface (`CustomResonse` in my Example) for which the CustomJsonDeserializer is used. This is not needed, but otherwise the Deserializer gets used for **every** request.

```
public class CustomConverterFactory {

    public static GsonConverterFactory create() {
        return GsonConverterFactory.create(createGsonCustomDeserializer());
    }

    public static Gson createGsonCustomJsonDeserializer() {
        return new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(CustomResponse.class, new CustomJsonDeserializer())
            .serializeNulls()
            .create();
    }
}
```

And for the Deserializer:

```
public class CustomJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<CustomResponse> {

@Override
public CustomResponse deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT,
        final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    if (json.isJsonObject()) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

        // Here you have to distinguish your class somehow
        // Maybe read some Json field from your response
        if (jsonObject.has("name")) {
            JsonElement classes = jsonObject.get("name");
            ...
            return context.deserialize(json, MyName.class);
        }
        ...
        // Default fallback: Deserialize as a fallback object
        return context.deserialize(json, MyFallback.class);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
```

Comment: i know this way .. but its a long way to do this.. still thanks for your reply ..

Comment: Either you know your desired Class before you perfom the request or you have to go this way.

Comment: thanks for that , i am still looking for some good solution .. i have this way .. for plan b.

Comment: Question, if I use this method in mine and some responses I receive from the server will be an object (IE User object, or a List of Event objects), but some will be straight booleans/ Strings), will this approach still work?